# What does a blue downward-pointing arrow inside a white circle at the bottom right of a macOS folder icon mean?

Tags: macos, icons

On macOS 10.15.4, what does the arrow on this folder icon mean?

[image: screen capture of icon]

Additionally, is there a name for the kind of thing this arrow is?  Is there a canonical reference?

Comment: What kind of sync are you using? Dropbox?

Comment: https://github.com/gridsync/gridsync